# Configure audit logging for Application Services in ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, aspnetboilerplate, audit-logging

I am trying to determine if there is a way to remove the Audit Logging that is provided by default in the ASP.NET Boilerplate code.

Looking at the documentation, it appears that removing the selector from the Auditing configuration with the following *should* work, but it doesn't.

```
Configuration.Auditing.Selectors.Clear()
```

The reason being, say, if I wanted to leave auditing enabled, but only wanted to audit certain services rather than all the services of type `IApplicationService`.

I have tried to put the above line in various modules, all with no success. All service calls are being logged in the `AbpAuditLogs` table.

Comment: In which method are you calling `Clear`?

Comment: The `Clear` is being called in the `PreInitialize` method in the `{APPNAME}CoreModule.cs` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Background

> ASP.NET Boilerplate provides the infrastructure to create application services.
>
> The **CreateControllersForAppServices** method gets an assembly and converts all the application services to MVC controllers in that assembly.
>
> ABP defines some **pre-built filters** for ASP.NET Core. All of them are added to **all actions of all controllers** by default.

— https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/AspNet-Core

## Problem

`Configuration.Auditing.Selectors.Clear()` handles it for [`AuditingInterceptor`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/c9b6368001ca8b4858a0ffc070ea02daf544bf6b/src/Abp/Auditing/AuditingInterceptor.cs), not action filters.

[`AbpAuditActionFilter`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/99ddf28e17f8b1a83d5ffdb51d97dce87ba87fcc/src/Abp.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/Mvc/Auditing/AbpAuditActionFilter.cs#L68) passes `defaultValue` as `true` to `_auditingHelper.ShouldSaveAudit(...)`.

The `defaultValue` is eventually returned by [`AuditingHelper`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/f95f88472627f375f6a9d942eecbf0d18fe335ef/src/Abp/Auditing/AuditingHelper.cs#L96).

## Workaround

We cannot replace `AbpAuditActionFilter` easily, but we can replace `AuditingHelper`:

1. Copy `AuditingHelper` and rename it to `IgnoreDefaultAuditingHelper`.
2. Modify the last line of `AuditingHelper.ShouldSaveAudit` to ignore `defaultValue`:

   ```cs
   public bool ShouldSaveAudit(MethodInfo methodInfo, bool defaultValue = false)
   {
       // ...

       return false;
       // return defaultValue;
   }
   ```
3. Replace `IAuditingHelper` in the `PreInitialize` method of your module:

   ```cs
   public override void PreInitialize()
   {
       Configuration.ReplaceService<IAuditingHelper, IgnoreDefaultAuditingHelper>();
   }
   ```