# How to Audit only desired methods or classes in Aspnetboilerplate?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, audit

In [official documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Audit-Logging) you can disable all the audit, or disable methods by [DisableAuditing]. But I want to audit only my desired methods or classes.

I implement MyCustomAuditStore but there isn't enough property to do what I want.

Comment: I want to Audit only the methods I want. in normal situation, all methods are audited in aspnetboilerplate @aaron

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure audit logging for Application Services in ASP.NET Boilerplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52956865/configure-audit-logging-for-application-services-in-asp-net-boilerplate)

Comment: Not exactly, but it helps

Comment: What's not working?